# Adding an "auto increment id field" to a union all access-sql-query result

Tags: sql, ms-access, union-all

Trying to add a new field "id field" to a simple union all sql query in Microsoft access like this one:

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.age FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.name, table2.age FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT table3.name, table3.age FROM table3 
;
```

which starts from 1 and increment automatically , is that doable?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name), *
FROM (
SELECT table1.name, table1.age FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.name, table2.age FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT table3.name, table3.age FROM table3 
) x
```

Comment: thanks for replying ,and it didn't got some error message about missing operator

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` not supported in Access SQL.